# Wavelet central frequency

Tags: frequency, wavelet, transform, bandwidth

What is the definition of the *central frequency* of a Wavelet and the *bandwidth* of a Wavelet? How do they affect the resultant waveform of the wavelet?

Thanks.

Comment: it looks like, in the case of the [Morlet wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlet_wavelet) there is an explicit answer to your question.  (and it is not exactly what i would expect, but i need to read it a little more.)  i don't know of a general definition of *"central frequency"* or *"bandwidth"* for every arbitrary wavelet definition.

Answer (score 1):

It's not formally defined, however I've seen $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \omega |\Psi(\omega)|^2 d\omega$ be used in the literature (i.e. the centre of mass of $|\Psi(\omega)|^2$), where $\Psi$ is the Fourier transform of the wavelet $\psi$.